# Debounce function called multiple times

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, lodash

I call following function within `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  loadData();
}, [amount]);
```

`loadData` function uses Lodash `debounce` function. When I update amount from input, `loadData` gets called several times depending on length of `amount` string.

```js
const loadData = useCallback(
  debounce(() => {
    console.log('called!');

    // Fetch data from API ...
  }, 1000),
  [amount]
);
```

In spite of using `useCallback` hook and 1s debounce. It returns multiple times. How to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The debounce function itself needs to be reused. With your code you're re-creating the debounce function callback every time amount changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `amount` changes, the `useCallback` generates a new function with a new debounce timer. To solve that pass `amount` a parameter to the function, and remove `amount` from the deps array of the `useCallback`:

```
const loadData = useCallback(
  debounce((amount) => {
    console.log('called!', amount);

    // Fetch data from API ...
  }, 1000),
  []
);

useEffect(() => {
  loadData(amount);
}, [amount]);
```